# Get numeric part from string using regex and c#

Tags: c#, regex

Anyone keen to show me how to get the integer part from this string using c#?

```
string url = "/{localLink:1301}";
```

I've been into using something like this but didn't get it to work properly

```
var getNumeric = new Regex(".*([0-9]+)");
```

Comment: Please show the whole of what you tried, and the results you got. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your expression could be as simple as `\d+`, given the assumption that there will be only one number in your input. Still under that assumption, using `ToString` on the resulting Match will give you what you are looking for.

```
var regex = Regex.Match("/{localLink:1301}", @"\d+");
var result = regex.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `.*` is greedy.  you either need `.*?` or `[^\d]*`

```
new Regex( ".*?(\d+)" );
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the match be greedy? You want to capture all of the numbers, not just the first one.

Comment: @vcjones, you want the numeric part to be greedy, not the part leading up to the numeric part.  the `.*` before the `[0-9]+` was matching the first 3 numeric digits since `.` matches any character.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this....

```
string output = new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```